# Excel 'Concatenate' with Alt+Enter, and then reference to another cell

Tags: excel, char, formula

This should be a simple process, but I am having difficulty producing the right outcome.  I am trying to combine three cells into one, with `Alt + Enter` or `Char(10)` separating each value.  When I use a simple Excel formula `=B2 & Char(10) & C2 & Char(10) & D2` and wrap the text of the destination cell, everything seems normal.  But if I try to search for a string in that cell (for example, "WS001"), it won't find the correct string.  If I use VBA to perform the same function (i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1) = Cells(2, 2) & Chr(10) & Cells(2, 3) & Chr(10) & Cells(2, 4)`), I can then search for the string in `B2` and it fill find it.

That problem was addressed (to a degree), but then when I try to link the destination cell to a cell in a different Worksheet (`=Sheet1!A2`), I encounter the same issue where the search function can't find the string.  Is there another method of doing this (I'd like to avoid VBA, because if someone has to edit the file/information in the future, they might not know how to change it)?

Comment: pnuts - I would like to be able to use the `Ctrl + Find` function.  In the first visual of Ken's answer, for example, I would do `Ctrl + Find` and search for "John".  While "John" is in both `A1` and `C1`, the search results would only be `C1` (I solved this issue by using VBA instead of a formula).  If I used a macro instead of a formula and linked cell `A1` to a different sheet, the `Ctrl + Find` still won't find "John" in the cell.

Comment: Thank you, that does find the correct cell, even when referenced from another worksheet.  Is there a way to have the concatenated cell 'look' the same way as if one hand-typed in the cell value (i.e. one value on each line)?  Right now the concatenated cell is a string with no spaces, but when the text is wrapped it seems as if the values are on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you are looking for based on this example?  Column A is the catenation of the three columns to the right, with CHAR(10).

Would you be for example searching for "Shane"?  What result would you want?

[image]

**EDIT**

I'm having trouble understanding what you're looking for, but hopefully this can send you in the right direction.

This is my result:

[image]

B1 is the data to be searched for

The catenated formula is as follows: (This also worked when they were on a different sheet)

```
=C6 & CHAR(10) & D6 & CHAR(10) & E6
```

The "Catenated result" search formula is an array formula (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter formula)

```
="Row "&MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND($B$1,A6:A8)))
```

The "Individual result" search formula is also an array formula (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter formula)

```
="Column "&MAX(($B$1=C6:E8)*COLUMN(C6:E8))-2
```

(the minus 2 is because the first Source Value" column is column C (ie 3)

Comment: Ken - if I searched for "Shane", I would want both the first cell (Row 2, Column 1) and the third cell (Row 2, Column 3) to display in the results.  From using the formula I mentioned above, the first cell won't appear as a cell with "Shane" in it.  If you used VBA to concatenate the three cells, then the first cell should be a result.  If in another cell you referenced the first cell (Row 2, Column 1) however, the search won't work regardless of which method was used.

Comment: Ken - you are correct, the `Find` function will locate the correct cell address (only after `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`).  However, if I use `Ctrl + Find`, it won't list cell `A6` when searching for "John".  If I use a macro to do the same concatenation, the `Ctrl + Find` function will locate cell `A6`.  If I then try to reference a cell on another worksheet to `A6`, however, then `Ctrl + Find` won't work again.

Comment: when you say Ctrl + Find are you meaning interactively pressing CTRL F ?  If so make sure you select the "Look in" drop down and select "Values" rather than "Formulas"